# How to check if a detached std::thread is still running?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

For a detached thread we can't use `joinable()` and using bool variables seems to be not the correct way. Is there a way to check if the detached thread is still alive and running?

Comment: A detached thread could write to a `std::atomic<T>` state variable to announce its termination

Comment: why do you detach it if you need to know its state?

Comment: What's your outer problem? Why do you care whether the thread is running or not? Most people who think they want to know if a thread is still running actually want to know if the thread has finished doing work. If this is not the case, why specifically do you care whether the thread is still running?

Comment: You should not detach threads on the first place. Similar to use of `const_cast`.

Comment: I have a blocking call in function A and I don't want my main function to be blocked after call to function A. I can't use join() it will also block so detached is the only way it seems. If there is any other way please suggest.

Comment: "Thread is finished/still running" is a meaningless bit of information. You are interested in "thread has/has not done its job". And this is what condition variables are for.

Comment: A stuck thread on a blocking call is a resource leak. It might be an idea to use a non-blocking version of whatever it is your doing if there is a non-blocking way.

Comment: @felix "joinable" doesn't imply "finished".

Comment: @n.m. No. I made a mistake.

Comment: Smells like XY problem

Comment: @galik there is not a non-blocking way as the function holds a streaming connection to server.

Comment: @PrashantShubham Sockets can be non-blocking...

Comment: @galik it's not a socket it's a grpc sync stream connection.

Comment: @PrashantShubham A quick look at the grpc documentation suggests it can be done using either non-blocking or through *deadline* timeouts?

Comment: @galik Async calls of grpc are also blocking for stream connections

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to tackle this.  If you're set on threads, then you can use a `std::future<void>` to detect when it has exited:

```
std::promise<void> promised_thread_exit;

std::future<void> thread_exited = promised_thread_exit.get_future();

std::thread(
  [] (std::promise<void> promised_thread_exit)
  {
    promised_thread_exit.set_value_at_thread_exit();
    DoBackgroundWork();
  },
  std::move(promised_thread_exit));
thread.detach();

// later...
thread_exited.get();
```

However, this seems like lot of work.  A `std::thread` is quite a low level primitive.  If the goal is just to perform some work in the background, then `std::async` is a better option:

```
std::future<void> work_complete = std::async(std::launch::async, DoBackgroundWork());

// later...
work_complete.get();
```

In either case, if you need to check on the work's state without blocking, you can do so by waiting on the `future` with a timeout of 0:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

//...

if (work_complete.wait_for(0s) == std::future_status::ready)
{
  // work has finished
}
```

That being said, checking the state like this is rarely necessary.  If it seems to be, then you should consider if there's a simpler alternative.

Comment: All of this will block, just like `thread::join`. The question is how to check that the work is done, not how to wait for the work to be done.

Comment: You can do a non-blocking check on the `std::future` by waiting with a timeout of 0 if needed.  (In the future--no pun intended--we'll have the `is_ready` method.)  But generally speaking, there are only two reasons we'd want to check if the thread is done: (1) to see if the result is ready so we can use it, or (2) to clean-up following cancellation.  `std::future` handles both those cases well.

Comment: Yes but perhaps you want this to be in the answer.

Comment: I've updated the answer, but it's not clear to me that the OP wants to do this.  His problem seems to be that he wants to start asynchronous work in a function but doesn't know how to wait for that work to complete outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `std::condition_variable` to notify your main thread when the detached one is finished:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable cv;

    std::thread t([&]() {
        std::cout << "Wait" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        std::cout << "Thread end" << std::endl;

        cv.notify_all();
    });

    t.detach();

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    cv.wait(lock);

    std::cout << "Main end" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```